# Work a Bitwise operation backwards

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I need to know how to do this backwards so that it will work for all of the options. If I start with shift i can get radix so How would i get shift from starting with radix.

```
int shift = 4; //3 will give octal base 4 will give Hex base 1 will give binary base
int radix = 1 << shift; // this comes out as 16
```

So Like i said above how would i get this to go the otherway

```
int radix = 16;
int shift =(some operation);
```

Also to make this work for if radix is 8, 2 or 16

Comment: Do you want to get the `shift` given a radix?

Comment: Yes that would be correct

Comment: Right shift by 1, till radix is 1?

Comment: You want the shift that applied to 1 gives you the radix, is that it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this method,

```
public static int radixToShift(int radix){
    int shift = 0;
    for(int i=0;radix >> i >1;i++){
        shift++;
    }
    return shift;
}
```

Code

```
int shift = 4; 
int radix = 1 << shift;
System.out.println("Radix :: "+radix);
System.out.println("Shift :: "+radixToShift(radix));
```

Output

```
Radix :: 16
Shift :: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of useful methods in the [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class. Try

`int shift = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(radix)`.